# Windows service shutsdown immediately after startup in docker container

Tags: c#, docker, windows-services, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I have a windows service written in `C#` that inherits from `ServiceBase`.
I have tried installing the service in the container (and also running as a console app), but it shuts down after a few seconds in daemon mode. If I run it interatively (`-it`) then it stays running. `OnStop` is called, but I can't determine what is calling it in daemon mode.

I have run with ping to keep the container alive :

```
docker run -d --name myapptest myapp ping -t localhost
```

docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework
SHELL ["powershell.exe", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; 
$ProgressPreference = 'Continue'; $verbosePreference='Continue';"]

RUN net user /add appuser Password1234!
RUN net localgroup administrators appuser /add

RUN New-Item -Path "C:/app" -ItemType directory

WORKDIR /app

COPY ".\hostcode" "C:\app"

RUN "C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/InstallUtil.exe" 
/username=.\appuser /password=Password1234! /LogToConsole=true /ShowCallStack myapp.exe
RUN SC.exe config MyApp start=auto

CMD POWERSHELL Write-Host Starting container... ; \
while ($true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 3600 }
```

Comment: Are you running it in interactive mode from docker?

Comment: When I run it in interactive mode it works. I don't want to run it in interactive mode though

Comment: I think you may have a misunderstanding about this: http://goinbigdata.com/docker-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint/

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have a misunderstanding about `RUN`, `CMD`, and `ENTRYPOINT`.
[This article](http://goinbigdata.com/docker-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint/) explains it well so check it out.

Try changing your docker file:

**from**

```
RUN SC.exe config MyApp start=auto

CMD POWERSHELL Write-Host Starting container... ; \
while ($true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 3600 }
```

**to**

```
ENTRYPOINT POWERSHELL Write-Host Starting container... && \
           SC.exe config MyApp start=auto
```

I'm guessing you put that infinite loop to keep the container alive but that really isn't needed so I took it out.